# Xamarin MultiTrigger in code

Tags: c#, xamarin, triggers

I am trying to get a Xamarin MultiTrigger working in code for a text length. Taking the example from here:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/triggers/

I have tried all sorts, Text.Length as the binding and all.

My code is as follows:

```
BindingCondition con = new BindingCondition()
{
    Binding = new Binding("EmailAddress", converter:new LoginTriggerConverter()),
    //Binding = new Binding("EmailAddress", converter: new LoginTriggerConverter(), source: "Text.Length"),
    Value = "false"
};
var multiTrigger = new MultiTrigger(typeof(Button));
multiTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter()
{
    Property = Button.IsEnabledProperty,
    Value = "true"
});
multiTrigger.Conditions.Add(con );
button.Triggers.Add(multiTrigger);

public class LoginTriggerConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        string data = (string) (value ?? string.Empty);

        if (data.Length > 0) // length > 0 ?
            return true;            // some data has been entered
        else
            return false;           // input is empty
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

The converter will not fire. I  change the Binding to:

```
    Binding = new Binding("EmailAddress", converter:new LoginTriggerConverter()),
```

The Converter fires, but the Button is still enabled when the length is 0.

Comment: Where is the `EmailAddress` definition (e.g. is it a property on a viewmodel instance), and where is the input element definition?

Comment: yeah sorry, Property of the ViewModel

Comment: If that is a string property, then the commented `Binding` would not work, because "Text.Length" doesn't make sense here. It looks like you are also trying to "monitor" an Input element that you haven't supplied code for.

Comment: I am trying to follow the link url, XAM uses Text.Length and the converter. I also get the model and converter executed, Button Enabled does not work though

Comment: But the binding path would need to be different (i.e. not the name of the viewmodel property) if you were binding to an input element. If you posted the snippet of XAML that defines the input element...

Comment: I don't have XAML for this. it's in c#

Comment: Ok, post that C# where the input element is defined.

Comment: Hi Mark, got it working without a converter :

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118042/discussion-between-paul-harding-and-mark-larter).